# If I have a matrix M=[A,B;0,C], how do I prove that rank(A)+rank(C)<=rank(M)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

```
.  .  .  .  .  .
.  A  .  .  B  .
.  .  .  .  .  .
0  0  0  .  .  .
0  .  0  .  C  .
0  0  0  .  .  .
```

If I have a matrix $M$ as displayed in the text above ($A$ and $C$ are distinct in rows and columns), how do I prove that $rank(A)+rank(C)\leq rank(M)$?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, $m=rank(A)$, $n=rank(C)$, $p=rank(M)$

The partial matrix $A$ has $m$ linear independent rows and the
partial matrix $C$ has $n$ linear independent rows.

If you fill up the rows of $A$ with zeros, and take the zeros of the zero-block
to $C$, you can easily see that you get $m+n$ linear independent rows of $M$.
So, $p\ge m+n$.

Answer (score 0):

let $rank(C) = c, rank(A) = a.$

let us look at the null space of $M.$ we have 
$$(x, y)^\top \in \ker(M) \iff  Ax + By = 0, Cy = 0 $$ pick a particular $y$ which has $\text{number of columns of } C - c$  free variables in it. we can solve $Ax = -By$ which will have $\text{number of columns of } A - a$ free variables in it.  therefore the total number of free variables in the solution to $Mx = 0$ is less or equal to $\text{number of columns of } A + \text{number of columns of } C - rank(A) - rank(C).$ therefore the rank of $M$ less or equal to the sum of the ranks of $A$ and $C.$  the reason that there may be fewer free variable is that they may be forced to zero by the constraint $Ax + By = 0.$

Comment: "we can solve Ax=−By which will have number of columns of A−a free variables in it."
I do not agree with it. It is equivalent to the statement that the matrix D=[A,B] has ker(D)=(number of columns of A)-a, which means that rank(D) is limited to a, which is not true.
Did I miss something?

Comment: @MatanLiram, are you not looking at $[A|B](x,y)^\top = 0$ without the companion $By = 0?$

Comment: Where did that companion come from? The original statement is Cy=0

Comment: @MatanLiram, i meant to write $Cy = 0.$

Comment: I still can't complete the missing part. How can I formalize the use of the companion's free variables?

Comment: @MatanLiram,   i am beginning to wonder if $B$ matters at all.

Comment: A nice way to see why the solution is right (and even a way to proof), is to apply row operators on A||B until A' is canonic, and column operators on B;C until C' is canonic. Then we can see that rank(M)>=rank(A')+rank(C') (since they are distinct in rows and in columns).

Comment: @MatanLiram, i think $rank(A) + rank(C) = rank(M);$  not less than.

Comment: I can find a counter example for that:
A is of order 2x1, C is of order 1x2, M is:
0,0,1;
1,0,0;
0,1,1
r(A)=1, r(C)=1, r(M)>r(A)+r(C)
notice that the example will work even if all of the sub-matrices are of order nxn

Comment: @MatanLiram, i see why the rank of $M$ may be strictly smaller than the sum. please see the edit.